# How to display/bind varbinary object from database into gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview, varbinary

I am trying to bind data from my database into my gridview. One of my columns contains varbinary(MAX) datatype. **When I bind it, my gridview displays System.Byte[] instead of the actual data.**

I have tried to deserialize object but I don't know where to go from there?
I have tried using my own ItemTemplate as well.

Table with VARBINARY:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TP_ShoppingCart] (
    [ShoppingCartID] INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Email]          VARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [ShoppingCart]   VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ShoppingCartID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_TP_ShoppingCart_TP_CustomerAccts] FOREIGN KEY ([Email]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TP_CustomerAccounts] ([Email])
);
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].TP_GetSalesByCustomer
    @theEmail varchar(250)
AS
    SELECT * FROM TP_Sales s JOIN TP_ShoppingCart sa ON s.ShoppingCartID = sa.ShoppingCartID
    WHERE s.Email = @theEmail AND sa.Email = @theEmail;
```

Gridview code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="SalesPanel" runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 table-bordered">
            <h1><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></span></small> Customer Sales</h1>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="gvSales" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SalesID" HeaderText="Sales ID" SortExpression="SalesID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SaleDate" HeaderText="Date of Sale" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Products">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblShoppingCart" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ShoppingCart") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ShoppingCart" HeaderText="Products" DataFormatString="" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SaleTotal" HeaderText="Sale Total" DataFormatString="{0:C0}" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

</asp:Panel>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void btnSalesAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CustomerAccountPanel.Visible = false;
            UpdateAccountPanel.Visible = false;
            CustomerCCPanel.Visible = false;
            UpdatePasswordPanel.Visible = false;
            SalesPanel.Visible = true;
            gvSales.Visible = true;

            DBConnect objDB = new DBConnect();
            SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand();
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            objCmd.CommandText = "TP_GetSalesByCustomer";

            //string email = Session["custEmail"].ToString();

            objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theEmail", email);

            gvSales.DataSource = objDB.GetDataSetUsingCmdObj(objCmd);
            gvSales.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(MAX), yourvarbincolumn, 0)

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) are more details on the choice of style (the third parameter).

And, here you need to convert binary datatype into varchar datatype, Lets pick it from your example:

CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [dbo].[TP_ShoppingCart].[ShoppingCart], 1) AS ShoppingCart

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), your_varbinary_column, 1) AS for_display
FROM your_table
```

convert the varbinary(max) column to varchar like in the code i have mentioned.

OR

Visit:http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/04/24/faq-displaying-image-from-database-to-gridview-control.aspx

for an alternative method u can use.